# How to shift timestamp for the rows in dataframe on the specific date

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on churn prediction use case and here is a part of the dataset (short version)

```
        ID  Timestamp 
    0   026 2017-07-01
    1   026 2017-08-01
    2   026 2017-09-01
    3   026 2017-10-01
    4   026 2017-11-01
    ... ... ... 
    283 327 2019-05-01
    284 327 2019-06-01
    285 327 2019-07-01
    ... ... ... 
    528 500 2018-01-01
    529 500 2018-02-01
```

Period of the observation is, for example, start date 2017-07-01 until 2019-12-01
First, I have to find all the users with the first date greater than the start date of the observation period ( 2017-07-01) and than shift all rows for them so that the first row starts with the date of the observation period.

For example, ID 026 is active from the start of the observation period, so that is ok - there is no transformation for him.

But ID 237 and 500 start activity later than the start of observation period and 
I should shift all dates (rows) starting from that point

after transformation dataframe should look like

```
        ID   Timestamp
    0   026 2017-07-01
    1   026 2017-08-01
    2   026 2017-09-01
    3   026 2017-10-01
    4   026 2017-11-01
    ... ... ... 
    283 327 2017-07-01
    284 327 2017-08-01
    285 327 2017-09-01
    ... ... ... 
    528 500 2017-07-01
    529 500 2017-08-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do a `groupby.cumcount` and offset:

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)

df['Timestamp'] =df.Timestamp.min() + pd.DateOffset(months=1) * df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
```

Output:

```
      ID  Timestamp
0     26 2017-07-01
1     26 2017-08-01
2     26 2017-09-01
3     26 2017-10-01
4     26 2017-11-01
283  327 2017-07-01
284  327 2017-08-01
285  327 2017-09-01
528  500 2017-07-01
529  500 2017-08-01
```

This approach set all data to **continuous** months starting from min date. If you want to just shift date, then a `groupby().transform('min')` woud do:

```
df.Timestamp -= df.groupby('ID')['Timestamp'].transform('min') -  df.Timestamp.min()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function to find the lowest date for each ID and work from there.

To get a dicitonary of how much you need to shift the timestamps in each ID by:

```py
shift_dict = {}
for id in df.ID.unique():
    shift = min(df[df['ID'] == id]['Timestamp']) - min(df[df['ID'] == '026']['Timestamp'])
    shift_dict[id] = shift
```

In dict comprehension:

```py
shift_dict = {id : ( min(df[df['ID'] == id]['Timestamp']) - min(df[df['ID'] == '026']['Timestamp']) ) for id in df.ID.unique()}
```